# Variable is not replaced by its value

Tags: javascript, node.js

am kind of novice to nodeJS and javascript, while trying to print a variable value, the variable isn't getting replaced by its value.

```
var a="World";
console.log("Hello ${a}");
```

am getting `"Hello ${a}"` instead of "Hello World"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use  **``**  instead of  **""** . For more see [**Interpolation in Javascript**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
var a="World";
console.log(`Hello ${a}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ES6 you can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) with placeholders (which you are trying to do it seems):

```js
var a="World";
console.log(`Hello ${a}`);
```

Other option is the traditional way, concatenating strings with the `+` operator:

```js
var a="World";
console.log("Hello " + a);
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can use this , you need to put assigned variable(a) out of string "" or else it will considered as a string**

```js
   var a="World";
console.log("Hello",a);
```